# Which type of Database Mapping is not supported in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In a interview I was asked a very strange question about Hibernate. Interviewer asked me "There are different types of mappings like One to One, One to Many. They all are supported by hibernate. But which database mapping is not supported by hibernate?"

Honestly I was blank and I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: "They all are supported by hibernate. But which database mapping is not supported by hibernate?" This seems to me a paradox....

Comment: what about non-relational mappings? like nosql ones?

Comment: @SCI That's not [strictly true](http://hibernate.org/ogm/). The interviewer is the one to blame here. Asking unclear questions in an interview is not a very good tactic.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Hibernate has no support for:

- NonSql Mappings
- Multidimensional Databases (as supported by Oracle)

Comment: Hibernate has an OGM for NonSql - so it supports NoSql

Comment: Multidimensional Databases - this are only the conjunctions from the four primary relations, I don't think that they add anything new, and as so I don't think that they can count as not supported by Hibernate.

Comment: But I like your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that all kinds of mappings are supported by Hibernate.

As a proof, this is the pretty obvious list of all possible mappings (relations) in a relational database:

- OneToOne
- OneToMany
- ManyToOne
- ManyToMany

All of them are supported by Hibernate.

Comment: If your answer holds true then what that guy was looking for?

Comment: @GD_Java He was just checking your knowledge, I don't like questions asking what doesn't exist, because it is hard to give a definitive answer, but in this case there are only four types of relations that are possible.

Comment: It's a bad answer. You claim to know what the interviewer was thinking about. You even declared that this is "The correct answer". This is all speculation on your part. Who knows what the interviewer was hoping to hear, but this does not (and cannot) answer the question.

Comment: @GD_Java We can only speculate what he was looking for. The way the question was posed is odd. Maybe he meant a different thing and used the wrong terminology.

Comment: I like your approach to first collect all possible relations and then showing, that they can be mapped in hibernate.
I'm just nor sure, if that is all.

Comment: by the way: the correct answer could have been (speculating here) "none", and this could be the proof for it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, i think Hibernate has no support for Matrix Databases (Managed with MQL-Matrix Query Language).